# Spring-WS WebServiceTemplate: What is the difference between HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender and HttpComponentsMessageSender?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

Aside from the latter having a persistent default httpclient, what else differ between the two? I also noticed roughly a 33% drop in transactions per second when using HttpComponentsMessageSender.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpComponentsMessageSender` uses [Apache Http Components](https://hc.apache.org/) implementation underneath.

`HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender` uses `java.net.URLConnection` as far as I remember.